# How to Handle Nulls in JSF Faces Flow

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, faces-flow

I have a faces-flow with three(3) pages. I have a date field which is sometimes null. Whenever the field is null i get the following error:
Full Stack Trace

```
javax.faces.component.UpdateModelException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:867)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processUpdates(UIInput.java:749)
at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processUpdates(UIForm.java:281)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1286)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processUpdates(UIComponentBase.java:1286)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processUpdates(UIViewRoot.java:1254)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.UpdateModelValuesPhase.execute(UpdateModelValuesPhase.java:78)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.put(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1124)
at javax.el.MapELResolver.setValue(MapELResolver.java:267)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._setValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:255)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.setValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:281)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.setValue(AstValue.java:238)
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.setValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:294)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.setValue(WeldValueExpression.java:64)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.setValue(TagValueExpression.java:131)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:832)
... 36 more
```

In the function below, if dateSigned is null the above error is shown. I have tried doing null checks but it doesn't work.

```
      public void saveWizard() {

        Map<Object, Object> flowScope = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getFlowHandler().getCurrentFlowScope();
        //Basic personal data
        person.setFirstName((String) flowScope.get("firstName"));
        person.setMiddleName((String) flowScope.get("middleName"));
        person.setLastName((String) flowScope.get("lastName"));
        person.setDateSigned((java.util.Date)flowScope.get("dateSigned"));
        personManager.save(person);
  }
```

Comment: please provide the full stacktrace. The Stacktrace you provide seems unrelated to the quoted method.

Comment: I really need help on this one